# elect our (Provisional) Moderators

Tags: discussion, poll, moderators, top-7

In accordance with [these guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57986/how-to-organize-a-formal-moderator-election-on-a-beta-se-site), we should be participating in *Moderator nomination discussions.* `Add another answer` to this question for your nomination for a moderator, and then *discuss!*

You can and should vote on any candidates you feel would make good moderators. If you were nominated, feel free to vote for other candidates, but it is bad form to vote for yourself. If you wish to retract or change a vote, you may need to edit the answer. Just open the edit window and save your changes without doing anything (you may need to add a space). The goal is that the people with the most upvotes represent the community's idea of who would make the best moderators.

Since the community has not been active for very long, and not everyone has come here from MathOverflow, nominees should edit their answers here to provide a brief description. In particular, **be sure to mention what times you will be browsing math.stackexchange.**

**Now that we have some new members in our group:** Let's get some nominations for members who were not involved in the private beta.

Candidates that declined nomination:
Edan Maor
Justin L 
Tom Stephens

Comment: Tom, could you make these all community wiki? In particular, I think it's important to have a short description for each candidate, and they should be able to add that themselves.

Comment: Please feel free to make edits to the above terms!  **Twenty-four hours** may not be a good time limit, **Four** moderators may not be the right amount, and maybe this is not how the process should proceed.  PLEASE EDIT!!

Comment: And we should have more than four candidates for four positions...

Comment: **HOW DO I MAKE SURE THAT I DONT GET REPUTATION FOR UP-VOTES HERE ?????**

Comment: @Tom: I don't think you'll get any. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56172/how-does-reputation-between-the-main-site-and-its-meta-work-on-se-2-0/56191#56191.

Comment: I recommend withdrawing the time limit altogether, based on [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57986/how-to-organize-a-formal-moderator-election-on-a-beta-se-site/58056#58056) from the StackExchange team. My understanding is that the point of this election is to serve as a guideline for them to appoint temporary moderators.

Comment: @Kaestur: Yes, I see what you're saying.  I will edit this question to come into line with that answer.

Answer (score 30):

## [**Katie Banks**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/76/katie-banks)

[meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/76/katie-banks)

---

I am a rising junior in pure and applied math at Harvard. My main mathematical interests are currently in differential geometry, topology, complex analysis and fluid mechanics, though they are always changing and growing. I've been tutoring high school and early undergraduate math, CS and physics for two years, and other levels for longer. I TAed the freshman intro to proofs class this year and taught geometry to high school students, and I'm very interested in STEM history, education and pedagogy, as well as the public's interaction with STEM. I've also participated in a few research projects in the general areas of discrete geometry and graph theory.

While I'm not an active poster on MathOverflow, I have been following both the site and its meta since November 2009 and I think I have a decent sense of both the goals and how things are run over there. I would like math.SE to complement MathOverflow, though also to allow a place for the broader scope and purpose that is being advocated by several people coming from StackOverflow, and to stand independently of MO. The strong sense of community on MO is something I want to build here. I have no experience with StackOverflow.

I'd most likely be on the site at times between 9PM - 2AM (EDT, GMT -4), and on and off 2PM - 6PM some afternoons. Caveat: This is likely to remain true for the schoolyear, but my level of participation will drop a little.

Comment: +1: Please tally this vote in the final count - I can't vote this up since I opened the thread.

Comment: what does it mean to be a "rising" junior, or freshman, or whatever? I have a vague idea of the term freshman and junior (year of undergrad?) but "rising"?

Comment: @Vivi: I think this is a relatively new term.  I heard it for the first time this summer... it means that this person will be entering ("rising" into) the class that they indicate.

Comment: thanks for that! I didn't even know what junior, senior, etc, meant, because this system is only used in the US as far as I know, but that I could solve with a bit of googling. The rising, though, was another story...  :)

Answer (score 21):

## [**Akhil Mathew**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/109/akhil-mathew)

[meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/109/akhil-mathew)

I am a rising freshman in mathematics at Harvard. I have diverse interests that are still growing and expanding, but currently lean towards algebraic geometry and dynamical systems. I've been involved in a few research mathematics projects, and one day I'd like to become a mathematician.

I also take an interest in mathematical exposition.    I did a fair bit of tutoring in high school (mostly in mathematics, but not exclusively). I've also been involved in the production of an undergraduate analysis textbook.  Since last November, I have maintained a mathematical [blog.](http://amathew.wordpress.com)

I would primarily be useful in the afternoons and evenings on Eastern time (namely, after 3). On Tuesday, Thursdays, and weekends, I'll probably be able to contribute during the mornings as well. (This is based on my current estimate of my schedule next year.)

I am an active MathOverflow user as well.  In addition, I've participated in the past on the Cogito.org online forums for high school students run by the Johns Hopkins University as a "host" of the mathematics section; this is a loose equivalent of "moderator," and is also part of what would influence my style if elected.

My vision for math.SE is a more open cousin to MathOverflow, one where good questions with clear answers  that are not at research level--or are based on research in related fields--are  encouraged quickly. MO has been very successful in its goal of making a community to ask questions about research math. We need one for just plain math.

Comment: +1: Please tally this vote in the final count - I can't vote this up since I opened the thread.

Answer (score 14):

## [**Kaestur Hakarl**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/73/kaestur-hakarl)

[meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/73/kaestur-hakarl)

---

It is my pleasure to introduce myself to a group of talented and enthusiastic individuals who share a love of math and a desire to build a friendly community built around posing and answering interesting mathematical questions. My real name is Larry Wang. I studied pure math at UC Berkeley, finishing my bachelors in May of 2009. While there, I taught calculus and statistics, as well as doing a lot of individual tutoring for a variety of math-related classes. Perhaps unwisely, I decided against pursuing graduate study and am now a computer programmer. My mathematical interests are probability, logic, and teaching.

Due to my profession, I have some presence on StackOverflow. I really admire the success they have had, both in creating a valuable repository of programming knowledge, as well as a friendly and helpful community. I love having the ability to just browse through the first few pages of questions at any time and find dozens of useful tips and insights about programming, and I think we're well on the way towards creating a similar experience here.

I am on CDT time (GMT-5) and Monday through Friday, can be online on and off in short bursts between 8AM and 6PM CDT. I will only have continuous blocks of time during the evening (7PM-9PM CDT), some days in the early morning (4AM-6AM CDT), and on the weekends (times vary widely). This might change in September when I switch jobs.

PS. The name comes from a variety of [pickled shark](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/73/kaestur-hakarl).

Comment: +1: Please tally this vote in the final count - I can't vote this up since I opened the thread.

Comment: I'm all for Kaestur too, he would be a deserving moderator.

Answer (score 9):

## [Isaac](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/72/isaac)

[meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/72/isaac)

I did some undergraduate and graduate coursework in math and computer science at Northwestern University, have a BA in math from New York University, was in the top 250 on the Putnam exam, and have an MAT in math from the University of Chicago.  I taught high school math, including courses through calculus and a lot of contest mathematics.  I was the lead editor for the most recent edition of a textbook on precalculus and discrete mathematics in one of the most widely-used preK-12 textbook series.  I currently freelance in various fields, including mathematical editing and math contest question-writing.

My knowledge base is strongest in real and complex analysis, calculus, advanced algebra/precalculus, geometry, and contest mathematics.  While I continue to freelance, I am likely to be on and off the site throughout my day, which is generally 10am to 2am central US time.  If I were to take a full-time job, this might change somewhat, but I would likely still be on fairly late at night.

I have spent time on StackOverflow and some time on other StackExchange sites, though I have spent virtually no time on MathOverflow (I have visited a few times, but graduate research mathematics is outside my general areas of interest).  My hope is that math.SE can be the appropriate place for the truly-mathematical questions arising from programming that crop up on SO, for the kinds of questions that I've heard teachers asking one another in the department office after class where no one quite knows the answer offhand, and for all those "I saw ___________ and it made me wonder what would happen if..." questions.

Comment: Congrats to Isaac on becoming the first unofficial moderator by breaking 2k!

Comment: @BBischof: Thank you.  Unfortunately, it seems that the statement "At the high end of this reputation spectrum there is little difference between users with high reputation and ♦ moderators" in the FAQ is misleading.  The so-called 10k-tools let me see a whole bunch of stuff and provide me with an easier way to retag questions, but the only new ability to *do* that I have is to vote to delete questions that have been closed for more than 2 days.  This is not much in the way of moderation power.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know much about what the challenging trail moderators can do that you can't, now I'm curious. (also I apologize for the skiing joke, every time I see that little diamond I think of it.)

Comment: @BBischof: I don't know exactly or for sure, but I believe that ♦mods can close a question single-handedly, can mass-manipulate tags in some fashion, and may have other powers like merging duplicate tags and/or questions, locking questions, deleting things, assigning "penalty box" account suspension (that might be reserved for admins--I don't know), or leaping tall buildings in a single bound (er, no, that's Superman, isn't it?).  It's kind of difficult to figure out, since the information is scattered on meta.SO, rather than in a single concise document.

Comment: @Isaac Maybe one of the main features of ♦mods is that they are allowed to know the full capabilities of ♦mods. Kinda like a fight club type rule.

Answer (score 8):

## [Qiaochu Yuan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/232/qiaochu-yuan)

[meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/232/qiaochu-yuan)

Comment: Qiaochu's answers have always been timely, spot on, and helpful. He is also one of the most influential MO users - at such a young age.

Answer (score 7):

## [**KennyTM**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/171/kennytm)

[meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/171/kennytm)

Comment: Kenny has, by far, the deepest experience of 10k tools of anyone who has substantially participated in the private beta, and he was very useful in the commitment phase.

Comment: Understanding the 10k tools is a big bonus, as it'd be very useful for the other moderators to have someone to ask about this stuff.

Comment: +1: Please tally this vote in the final count - I can't vote this up since I opened the thread.

Answer (score 4):

## [**Bryan Bischof**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/16/bbischof)

[meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16/bbischof)

Comment: +1: Please tally this vote in the final count - I can't vote this up since I opened the thread.

Answer (score 0):

## [**Jason S**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/120/jason-s)

[meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/120/jason-s)

Comment: -1: Superposition answer was silly.