# Do we need moderators pro tempore right now?

Tags: discussion, moderators, poll

Per [this post on the SO/SE blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) (which, curiously, does not include math.SE in its graphic list), it looks like the admins will choose moderators pro tempore at about 7 days into the public beta.  In the roughly 24 hours that we've been in public beta, I've wondered several times: should we push to have the admins choose moderators pro tempore sooner (e.g. *now*)?

*edit*: to try to get a bit more clarity in response to this question, I've created CW answers "YES" and "NO" below--please up/down vote those as you see fit.

*edit2*: see also: [elect our (Provisional) Moderators](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150/elect-our-provisional-moderators)

Comment: Especially because things arent getting closed fast enough..

Comment: Unfortunately only 13 users (at time of writing) are able to vote to close.

Comment: And we're limited to 12 votes to close per day.

Comment: 12 votes times 14 users with rep >= 500 / 5 votes needed makes 33 discussion per day which could be closed :-)

Wouldn't it be better to finish building the FAQs first?

Comment: @Isaac: No "Math.SE" graphic because Math.SE was still in *private* beta when the post was written.

Comment: @Robert: The time on the blog entry is about 20 minutes after public access to math.SE was available, but I figured it was because the private/public switch was in progress as the blog entry went up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**YES** we do need moderators pro tempore now

Comment: I think this is a good idea because (besides the administrative aspect): This would be a good opportunity to project a quasi-coherent message of purpose in these early days.

Comment: can I down vote the pun... I'm kidding I'm kidding.

Answer (score 5):

The Moderator Pro Tem program is just about complete. **I don't have an objection** to bumping up Math.SE in the schedule a few days (would have been on Tuesday, 8/3 anyway). The meta activity has been pretty solid. That's assuming there isn't any wide-spread objection from here or higher-on up.

<sup>*Sorry to break in on your YES/NO thread.*</sup>

Answer (score -1):

**NO** we do not need moderators pro tempore now

Comment: lol, I read this answer and was like "jeeze, whats his problem, he doesn't even give a reason here, just...Oh nevermind, he also posted the yes version..."

Comment: yeah, I was getting a feeling from the comments and the up-votes on the question that "yes" was probably a popular answer, but I wanted something a bit more explicit (especially if it'll help if emailing the admins to ask for it to happen)